# Sylius Cart Bundle product variable not found

Tags: symfony, cart, sylius

I've installed SyliusCartBundle.

I want to add items to my cart, but when I try to do this action I get: "Variable "product" does not exist in SyliusCartBundle:Cart:summary.html.twig at line 7"

summary.html.twig

```
{% set cart = sylius_cart_get() %}

Current cart totals: {{ cart.total }} for {{ cart.totalItems }} items!

<a href="{{ path('sylius_cart_item_add', {'productId': product.getId() }) }}">Add product to cart</a>
```

syliusAction()

```
/**
 *
 * @Route("/sylius")
 */
public function syliusAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('DTRBundle:Product')->find(2);

    return $this->render(
        'SyliusCartBundle\views\Cart\summary.html.twig',
        array(
            'product' => $product
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you have something if you dump `$em->getRepository('DTRBundle:Product')->find(2);` in your controller? (before the response)

Comment: yes, I get the product from database